# Flex ComboBox - Removing Borders

Tags: apache-flex, combobox, flex3

Does anyone know how to remove the small border around the combobox?

In a Flex3 Combobox (Halo Theme) there is this little gray border at the left, right, and bottom edges. I want to remove those borders so that the button part of the combobox doesn't have any border at all. Instead, I just want the top border.

Any ideas how it can be done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to replace the Class that's used by default in the skin css property with one of your own. The docs say that is defined in ComboBase, so you'll need to look there to see what the Class is there and if you can extend or even do away with it (by setting skin to an empty ClassReference).